# Similarity measure between training and testing loss to identify overfitting

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, overfitting

I am new to machine learning and I would like to know whether my trained CNN is overfitting. So I have drawn the curves training and testing losses versus the training epochs.

I have trained my CNN for about $50$ epochs with a learning rate equal to $10^{-3}$ that decreases every $3$ epochs by a factor $0.5$.

I found an answer to this question [How to Identify Overfitting in Convolutional Neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204062/how-to-identify-overfitting-in-convolutional-neural-network) but I couldn't find an exact similarity measure between the testing and training error/loss to make a decision.

I have attached the figure of these curves below and I would appreciate any comment.

[image: Training and testing losses versus training epochs]

Comment: @Sycorax How could it be a duplicate?
I am asking a very specific question about my own simulation.
I have already seen that question but couldn't tell if it is overfitting or not given my simulations.

Comment: Teach a man to fish...

Comment: @Sycorax When you go through the literature there is no an exact measure to tell how similar should be both errors or losses.
And you think that I didn't even try to fish..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't agree with a point made in the linked answer:

> Comparing the performance on training (e.g., accuracy) vs. the performance on testing or validation is the only way (this is the definition of overfitting).

To me, this is *not* the definition of overfitting.  Instead, I take as a definition (or, at least, the way to identify overfitting):

> A one parameter family of models, parameterized by some measure of model complexity, is *overfit* when a small increase in model complexity leads to a decrease in test set performance.

This is more in line with the usual pictures: the optimal model fit is at a *minimum* of test set error.

In your case, your measure of complexity is training epochs.  In your plot, the testing error rate has *not yet* begun to increase as you add more training epochs, so your model is not overfit.

Comment: Would it be better to train my network $N$ times then plot the average errors for both testing and training. Would the interpretation remain the same?